# jQuery's $('#divOne').animate({zIndex: -1000}, 2000) does not work?

Tags: jquery, z-index, jquery-animate

I tried jQuery's

```
$('#divOne').animate({zIndex: -1000}, 2000)
```

to that element which has a z-index of 1000, but it is still above the other elements?

(If I use firebug to change it to `-1000` then it will be below other elements)

Comment: What effect are you trying to go for? Animating the z-index won't do much good. Even if the z-index was progressively lowered, you would only notice a (non-animated) change at the point where the high/low values switched and it became less than the other elements.

Comment: @munch: I can see how this would work. Consider a stack of cards, and a card rippling down through the stack. Mind you, it'll only work if there are a bunch of cards with z-indexes in the range between where that element starts and -1000...

Comment: Is there any docs that says animate() won't work for z-index?

Comment: malsup states here http://jquery.malsup.com/cycle/adv.html do not try to animate the z-index in ie for example

Comment: @munch I also need this as I have another animation going on that uses the z-index as part of the basis for calculating position on the page; ie. higher z-index == closer == larger. If you just jump the z-index then this calculation also jumps and looks horrible.

Comment: This has also been fixed as of jQuery 1.5.1, so if at all possible, the easiest solution is just to update the version of jQuery you are using.

Answer (score 37, accepted):

jQuery attempts to add a unit to the value on each step of the animation. So, instead of `99` it'll be `99px` which, of course, isn't a valid `zIndex` value.

It doesn't seem possible to set the unit used by jQuery to simply a blank string -- it'll either take the unit you include in the value (e.g. `20%` - percent unit) or it will use `px`.

Fortunately, you can hack `animate()` to make this work:

```
var div = $('#divOne');

$({
    z: ~~div.css('zIndex')
    // ~~ to get an integer, even from non-numerical values like "auto"
}).animate({
    z: -1000
}, {
    step: function() {
        div.css('zIndex', ~~this.z);
    },
    duration: 2000
});
```

For more info about `~~` see [this](http://james.padolsey.com/javascript/double-bitwise-not/).

Comment: Is there a minimum jQuery version for this? I just attempted to do this with jQuery 1.2.6 and unfortunately it isn't doing anything at all. I tried adding a complete function, and even that wasn't being called by the animation.

Comment: I have the same question as Matthew. I'm using jquery 1.5.1, and I can see the image switching but without the animation.  If anyone ever see this comment and know the answer ...please share it with the world

Comment: I tried this solution (copied exactly as is) and it works fine: I get a nice animation and the zIndex changes not directly on click but after the defined time: perfect animation. But if I say e.g. z: 1, and then inside step div.css('zIndex', 100); (or "100") to go from 1 to 100: the zIndex doesn't change as expected with the smooth transition. Any ideas how? Or how to modify this example to make it work with manual values instead of working with ~~ ? Thanks

Comment: If you need to manually change the zIndex -with a smooth animation of course- without using the ~~ option (which I was not able to control and customize to my needs) you may find this one useful:
setTimeout(function () {
                $("#product-1").css('zIndex', '2');
                $("#product-2").css('zIndex', '1');
            }, 500);

Answer (score -2):

<strike>You cannot animate the zindex.</strike> You can set it using [.css](http://api.jquery.com/css/).

`$("#divOne").css('z-index' , '-1000');`

Comment: I thought animate() is supposed to be able to animate anything (reasonable) within CSS?  (something that has a scalar value)

Comment: hmm, well I am yet to see a 3d browser!

Comment: animating z indexes is pretty useful for things like this: http://jsfiddle.net/ejvsY/122/

Comment: @Bob Kruithof that js does not even mention z-index!

Comment: didn't say so, just said it would be pretty useful for things like that ;)

Comment: the selected answer given by @999 is correct but there is nothing wrong suggested by redsquare as well. its highly recommendable to set the z-index through css and then start the remaining animation for cross browser support. cheers!