# How to change position and z-index using jquery (animate)

Tags: javascript, jquery

Is there any way to change an animation also the position and the z-index of a div?

Here's the code and what I'd like is the property to be set on mouse click in this order.

```
<script>
        jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {
            var youtubeVid = '<iframe src="//www.youtube.com/embed/Jcjsrt-xWdo" width="100%" height="100%" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen="" id="fitvid670345"></iframe>';
            $("#home-page-vid-image").on("click", function () {
                $("#home-page-vid-image").animate({    
                    position: "absolute",
                    z-index: "2",                
                    top: "463px",
                    width: "100%",
                    height: "541px"                  
                }, 1000, function () { $("#home-page-vid-image").html(youtubeVid)});               
            });
        });
</script>
```

If its not possible, any suggestion about how can I do this?

Comment: maybe `'z-index'` with quotes, or `zIndex` without quotes. javascript property cannot have a dash `-`.

Comment: Or you can use style attribute

Comment: replacing the dash with zindex, both position and zindex property are not setted

Comment: It's `zIndex` with a capital `I`, it's generally referred to as camelCase and used for styles in javascript.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot animate the `position` and `z-index` attributes with jQuery. Try this:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {
    var youtubeVid = '<iframe src="//www.youtube.com/embed/Jcjsrt-xWdo" width="100%" height="100%" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen="" id="fitvid670345"></iframe>';
    $("#home-page-vid-image").on("click", function () {
        $("#home-page-vid-image")
            .css({position: "absolute"})
            .animate({                       
               top: "463px",
               width: "100%",
               height: "541px"                  
            }, 
            1000, 
            function () { 
               $(this)
                   .css({zIndex: "2"})
                   .html(youtubeVid);
            });               
    });
});
```

Or if you really need the z-index to gradually change you can use the `step` parameter of `animate` as shown in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3123079/932282) answer.