# Jquery or Javascript Animating the Z-Index

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, animation

I need the functionality of animating the z-index property of a specific HTML object.  I've been able to achieve this animation in two ways that both have their difficulties/drawbacks.  Successfully answering this question for me will fix one of the following two issues:

The first is by adapting the JQuery animate command with the step functionality outlined here by the accepted answer:

[jQuery's $('#divOne').animate({zIndex: -1000}, 2000) does not work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3122926/jquerys-divone-animatezindex-1000-2000-does-not-work)

The problem with this method for me is that the $('#obj').stop(); command cannot prematurely end the animation when done in this way.  It always finishes unless I destroy the object I'm working with and create a new one (which causes blinking obviously).  If anyone knows of a way to properly stop a step animation like this, or a work-around for the issue, I'd love to see it.

```
var div = $('#obj');

$({z: ~~div.css('zIndex')}).animate({z: [-2000, 'linear']}, {
    step: function() {
        div.css('zIndex', ~~this.z);
    },
    duration: 10000
});
```

The second is using a setInterval loop on 20 MS (a speed that is sufficient for my needs) to simply adjust the z-index to what it should be at that point of the "animation".  This works great for a few moments, then something causes it to stop working suddenly.  The code still runs through the $('#obj').css('z-index', val); line, and val is changing, but it no longer updates the object in the DOM.  I've tried it on slower timer settings as well with identical results. Anyone know why JQuery might suddenly no longer be able to set the Z-Index?

```
function () move {
    if (!(MoveX == 0 && MoveY == 0))
    {
        $('#obj').css('z-index', val);
    } 
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`$('#obj').stop()` doesn't work for you because **the animation isn't being performed on `$('#obj')`**.

It is being performed on the object `$({z: ...})` (with a custom step function). This means you should do something like

```
var anim = $({z: ~~div.css('zIndex')}).animate({z: [-2000, 'linear']}, {
  step: function() {
    div.css('zIndex', ~~this.z);
  },
  duration: 10000
});

// sometime later
anim.stop();
```

See this [demo](http://plnkr.co/edit/mwVEtKzlqgWF0wjwzIws?p=preview).

---

**Edit** For what it's worth, [here](http://plnkr.co/edit/ve8Q5dxJG9KVVaet1OI6?p=preview) is the same demo using an animation interval. I see a syntax error in your second snippet: the function declaration should be

```
function move() { ...
```

I assume that's a typo since your code wouldn't even parse. Other than that, I'm not sure why that solution didn't work for you.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I can't wait to try it! I'll post back in a few hours with whether it worked or not.

This code is from a home project and I re-wrote it from memory directly into stackoverflow rather than copying and pasting so it makes sense that I made a typo :D

Comment: Worked perfectly.  A solid answer to a solid question.